# Accesing to a children via script on a Parent-Children relation in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Using ES 2.3.2 and having a parent, `item` and a children, `user_item_relation` with the following mappipng:

```
 "mappings": {
    "item": {
       "dynamic": "strict",
       "properties" : {
            "title" : { "type": "string"  },
            "body" : { "type": "string"  },
            "source_id" : { "type": "integer"  },
            "time_order" : { "type": "string"  },
            "source_type" : { "type": "integer" }
        }
    },
    "user_item_relation": {
      "_parent": {"type": "item" },
      "properties" : {
            "user_id" : { "type": "integer"  },
            "item_id" : { "type": "integer"  },
            "source_id" : { "type": "integer"  },
            "favorite" : { "type": "integer"  },
            "pending" : { "type": "integer"  },
            "tags" : { "type": "string"  },
            "featured" : { "type": "integer" }
}}}}'
```

I know I can update for example the a value of `source_type` which is located on parent (`item`) to 133 for all the documents that match the query (`title` has the word `duros` and the children (`user_item_relation` has `user_id = 1234`) using the `_update_by_query` script.

```
curl -X POST 'myip:9200/my/_update_by_query' -d'{
"query": {
  "bool": {
     "must": [
        {
           "query_string": {
              "default_field": "title",
              "query": "duros"
           }
        },
        {
           "has_child": {
              "type": "user_item_relation",
              "query": {
                 "term": {
                    "user_id": 1234
}}}}]}},
  "script" : { "inline" : "ctx._source.source_type = 133"}
}'
```

But when I try to change a value of the children with the same query (`ctx._source.favorite = 0`)

```
curl -X POST 'myip:9200/my/_update_by_query' -d'{
"query": {
  "bool": {
     "must": [
        {
           "query_string": {
              "default_field": "title",
              "query": "duros"
           }
        },
        {
           "has_child": {
              "type": "user_item_relation",
              "query": {
                 "term": {
                    "user_id": 1234
}}}}]}},
  "script" : { "inline" : "ctx._source.favorite = 0"}
}'
```

The following error is shown:

> {"took":1481,"timed_out":false,"total":1,"updated":0,"batches":1,"version_conflicts":0,"noops":0,"retries":0,"failu
>   res":[{"index":"my","type":"item","id":"10","cause":{"type":"strict_dynamic_mapping_exception","rea
>   son":**"mapping set to strict, dynamic introduction of [featured] within
>   [item] is not allowed**"},"status":400}]}

As you can read it's trying to modify a value of the field `featured` on the parent (`item`) that doesnt exist, because it's on the children and not on the parent.

How can I change the script line so I can get the value of the `favorite` (which is on the children `user_item_relation`) to `0`?

Comment: I don't think that's possible because the query matches parent documents, not children. You need a query that matches children documents.

Comment: But the content that I want to search, `title` or `body` are always in the `item` (parent). So is there any other way to archieve what I want to do?

Comment: Run two queries: one gets the parents. Then with the list of parents you create a query on the children documents with `has_parent` query where you specify the list of parent IDs.